# Concat the columns in Pandas Dataframe with separator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe say `df_dt_proc` with 35 columns.

I want to add a column to the dataframe `df_dt_proc['procedures']` which should have all the columns concatenated except column at index 0 separated by `,` .

I am able to achieve the result by the following script:

```
df_dt_proc['procedures'] = np.nan

_len = len(df_dt_proc.columns[1:-1])

for i in range(len(df_dt_proc)):
    res = ''

    for j in range(_len):
        try:
            res += df_dt_proc[j][i] + ', '
        except:
            break
    
    df_dt_proc['procedures'][i] = res
```

However, there must be a more pythonic way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with remove `NaN` and `None`s and converting to strings, for select all columns without first and last use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
f = lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(str))
df_dt_proc['procedures'] = df_dt_proc.iloc[:, 1:-1].agg(f, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `agg`:

```
df_dt_proc['procedures'] = df_dt_proc[df_dt_proc.columns[1:-1]].astype(str).agg(', '.join, axis=1)
```

Comment: This is working fine. What if we have blanks values in a few columns? I am getting error - `expected str instance, float found`.

Comment: @gm-123 Edited my answer, please upvote and accept if it works

Comment: it appends `nan` for all the empty columns. Result looks like `'Atrial Septal Defect (ASD) Repair, Bentall Procedure, CABG - Redo, Cardiac Valve Replacement, Closed Heart Surgery, Coronary Artery Bypass Grafting (CABG), Heart Double Valve Replacement, Heart Port Surgery, Heart Transplant, VSD Closure / Repair (Adult), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan'`